# Convert string with time zone to datetime in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2008+ I can use `Convert(datetimeoffset, 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ', 127)`.

SQL Server 2005 does not have `datetimeoffset`. How can I convert the string with time zone to date time?

I can format the string as needed.

Ref:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, or at least you cannot retain the timezone if you want to convert the string in a date type.
If the data will be later managed with a program you can resolve to store the string, if you need to check it with query you can store the timezone information in another column.

Another possibility is to translate the date to a common timezone before the insert.